# Is it possible to analyse the PhoneGap app cache on Android or iOS?

Tags: caching, webview, cordova, phonegap-build

A trawl of SO does not directly answer this question. I use Phonegap build to wrap my HTML5 application.

The app builds lists of data and presents some forms by creating DOM structures from XHTTP requests that are JSON data.

Over time the cache builds up. I can see the overall size under Settings=>Application Manager=> "My App".

What I want to know is how can I interrogate this cache and look at its contents for Android (and ideally for iOS as well) ? I need to know if user content is being cached, or is it just the underlying installed files of HTML and JS being cached in webview ? I suppose this question also goes to the inner workings of Phonegap as well

Comment: someone says, you don't need it at all, check it [here](http://www.raymondcamden.com/2015/02/26/reminder-you-dont-need-appcache-for-phonegapcordova)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a way to view the cache via PhoneGap? No. However, there are a few methods you can use to view the cache. Take a look at the answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9916829/how-do-i-view-android-application-specific-cache). The easiest method might be to view it via a rooted device your app is installed on.