# How to find an application cache on an android device from linux

Tags: android, adb, data-recovery

I accidentally deleted my private key from my email (protonmail) on PC and didn't have it saved anywhere, and can't decrypt any of my old emails. I tried contacting the support but it was no help. I noticed that I can still read older emails fine on my phone and it even encrypts newly sent emails with the old key. I tried asking the support how to extract the key but they said it can't be done. So I'm trying to find it myself and add it to my account again. I think it's cached and the application haven't queried for the new key yet.
The problem is I don't know anything about android or where the files are stored.
I tried connecting my device (Moto G 5G) to my linux and searching through the files with no luck, the application folder is empty, but the phone shows there is data in the cache (around 57kb).

I searched around and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9916829/how-do-i-view-android-application-specific-cache). But I never used adb and I'm unable to find the device from adb and I couldn't find drivers in case it was a driver issue.

My question is why I can't find any application cache? Is it a permission issue? And is there a way to extract it from my phone? If it's a complicated issue then can you please point me to the right place to read more on connecting to android or how to get started as I can't find proper docs to do so. Thanks

Comment: On non-rooted phones you don't have access to the app private data. Depending on the app the cryptographic key may even be imported to AndroidKeystore where export is not possible. Therefore if the app developer tells you that key export is not possible then with a high chance this is true.

Comment: @Robert I see, thanks for clarifying that. I am still talking to support and maybe they can help me.